# modifying query string in url without reloading

Tags: jquery, asp.net

am filtering the products by passing the querystring. but problem is that every time i select a filter querysting is appending to url and reloading the page. i don't want to reload the page just pass the querystring and filter the products by making the ajax call. **just like [flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com/laptops/dell~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g&_pop=flyout&otracker=hp_submenu_computer)  is doing**

this is  [my page](http://www.superfashioner.com.falcibar.arvixevps.com/category.aspx)

please let me help with these.

Comment: So why even append to the url ? Can you not store your selected values in local variables and then make the ajax call ?

Comment: a link to your web page is not a substitute for posting the relevant code in your question. There can be many scripts in a page and in the future the url may change rendering your post useless for future visitors with similar problems

Comment: because i want to bookmark the filtered stuff. @ryadavilli

Answer (score 4):

You can use `jquery ajax`. It is too simple

You need to create an ashx/asmx page which will return the results based on the url parameters passed. I suggest to return a `JSON` as the result.

jQuery ajax can be used as below. [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "GetItems.ashx?design=1";
}).done(function() { 
  alert("Got the results");
});
```

Then you can use jQuery templates to render the JSON data. [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/)

Comment: besides i want to bookmark the url of the filtered stuff. i think these way passing query sting to ajax and returning the result. am passing to browser url. for reference see filpkart link above and let me confirm does flipkart funcationality happens by said method. thanking you

Comment: For this you can use some URL hash/fragment based techniques. In th e URL, put a # and save your data after that. Checkout [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/). This can be used for processing the URL values. `deparam.fragment()` can be used for this

Comment: how to push the state with same keys for different values. for ex: design=1 and design=2

but the problems is that its replacing the value of design while i was pushing another value from design key. because i need both design=1&design=2 in the querystring so that i can filter accordingly

please help me with these

Comment: It is not  good idea to use same keys more than once. Instead you could use design=1#2 or something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Some HTML5 compatible web browsers has implemented an History API that can be used for something similar to what you want:

```
if (history.pushState) {
    var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?myNewUrlQuery=1';
    window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
}
```

I tested, and it worked fine. It does not reload the page, but it only allows you to change the URL query. You would not be able to change the protocol or the host values.

For more information:

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history